# MapInfo Styles in Oracle Spatial Database

Tags: mapinfo, mapserver, ogr, style, oracle-spatial

I have geographic data in an Oracle database. The data was imported by EasyLoader, which is a MapInfo-Tool. I want to publish this data in a Web Map Service. I have tried to use MapServer, but I have problems handling the styles.

I know that the in MapServer, it is possible to get the correct styles by OGR, if they are in a TAB-File.

```
CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
CONNECTION "Cables.TAB"
STYLEITEM "AUTO"
```

The same data is in the database and I created an new layer section:

```
CONNECTIONTYPE PLUGIN
PLUGIN "msplugin_oracle.dll"
STYLEITEM "AUTO"
```

An error occurs

```
General error message. 'STYLEITEM AUTO' not supported for this data source.
```

If I define a manual style with

```
CLASS
    STYLE
        COLOR 0 0 0
        WIDTH 2.5
    END
END
```

the lines are shown.

So here is the question: Is there any possibility to use the AUTO StyleItem with an oracle spatial database to decode the mapinfo style?

Or do you have any suggestions, how I could use this information for styling my items?

Answer (score 1):

When loading MapInfo tables into a spatial database such as Oracle, MS SQL Server or PostgreSQL/PostGIS, MapInfo Pro/MapInfo EasyLoader can store the styling information in two ways.

1. It can be stores in the MapInfo.MapInfo_MapCatalog as a single style per table
2. It can be stored as an attribute in a separate column for each record in the spatial table.

In both cases the styling information is stored using the MapBasic style definitions:

- Pen
- Brush
- Symbol
- etc.

So you need to extract the styling information directly from the either the MapInfo_MapCatalog or from the style column (often named MI_STYLE) in the tables.

There's a similar thread here discussing how to get the styling information from MapInfo tab files for use in a WMS server: [What's the easiest way (style wise) to publish my MapInfo map as WMS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42753/whats-the-easiest-way-style-wise-to-publish-my-mapinfo-map-as-wms)

Alternatively, you can have a look at using [Spectrum Spatial](http://support.pb.com/help/spectrum/11.0/webhelp/en/Spatial/index.html#Spatial/source/LandingPageForHelp.html) as a WMS server. Spectrum Spatial is sold by Pitney Bowes who I also work for (full disclosure).